# generate monthly date from 1st to 1st

Tags: php, date

the code below will generate day for each and month.. How do i list the date until the first day of the following month...

example 1st January to 1st February, 1st May to 1st June...etc

```
<?php

$month = "01";
$year = "2017";

$start_date = "01-".$month."-".$year;
$start_time = strtotime($start_date);

$end_time = strtotime("+1 month", $start_time);

echo "<table border='1'>";

for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time; $i+=86400)
{
$list = date('Y-m-d-D', $i);
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $list;
echo "</td><td> </td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create a function so you can use it again without having to duplicate code. Read the comments inside to see what each line does.

```
<?php

function genMonthTable($month, $year){
    /* Get days in month */
    $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

    /* Add 1 extra day to get first day of the next month */
    $days+=1;

    /* Instantiate DateTime object */
    $date = new DateTime();

    /* Set date */
    $date->setDate($year, $month, 1);

    /* Create table */
    echo "<table style='border: 1px solid black;'><tbody>";

    /* Loop table rows */
    for($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++){
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
        echo "</td></tr>";

        /* Increate date by 1 day */
        $date->modify('+1 day');
    }

    /* Finish table */
    echo "</tbody></table>";

    /* Unset DateTime object */
    unset($date);
}

/* Generate table for Januari 2017 */
genMonthTable(1, 2017);

/* Generate table for May 2017 */
genMonthTable(5, 2017);

?>
```

Comment: thank you very much bro but the date listed is only from 1st until end of month and not until 1st of the following month ..i would like it to be 1,2,3 jan..to 1 feb

Comment: @blackrx That's easy. Just do `$days+=1;` underneath `$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);` I've edited the code for you.

Comment: btw if in the original code is it possible to do this ?

Comment: @blackrx I'm not sure. It's a pretty strange way of doing it. I would have to tinker around with it and see for myself

Comment: @blackrx And yes, it is. You gonna laugh about this one though. Just change `$i<$end_time;` to `$i<=$end_time;` in your code and it will work, lol

Comment: haha that was super easy lol but i prefer your code..thanks again..have a good day